# How to insert links in the slices of a pie chart (R)?

Tags: r, knitr, pie-chart

I'm currently working in R. I'm creating the final document to present my data in html with the "knitr" package.

My question is, if a have a pie chart with 4 slices but each slice has information to be analyzed, is there a way to hyperlink each slice of the pie so they send me to the bar that explains it?

Does it only work in the same document or is there an option to open a new window where the information in the slice is going to be shown?

Thanks in advance.

The following is the r-chunk where I create the pie-chart

```
DATA<-cbind(c(1:4),c(44737,42063,48899,50259))

del<-c(DATA[,1]) 
names <- paste(c("NW","NE","SW","SE"), "\n", del, sep="")
pct <- DATA[,2]/sum(DATA[,2])*100
pct <- round(pct, digits=2)

names <- paste(names, "\n", pct)
names <- paste(names, "%", sep="")

pie(DATA[,2], labels = names,  col = rainbow(length(names)),
   main="ZONE")
```

Each one of the slices in the pie is the sum of frequencies of patients in hospitals in that zone, (Northwest, Northeast,...) I want to have a link so when I click the slice, I get redirected to the bar that shows the info about the hospitals.

Thanks again.

Comment: Don't make a pie-chart. Piecharts are [bad](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2009/04/pie-charts-are-bad/).

Comment: I don't like them either, but my boss want them. I'm working also in the document without pie charts, with barplot, unfortunately I need to know how to do this, with pie or with bar.

Comment: Can you make your question reproducible? Show some data/code, it makes it easier for others to help you

Comment: Done, I'm so new here, thanks.

Comment: Perhaps packages like [`googleVis`](http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/googleVis/html/gvisPieChart.html) or, more likely, [`rCharts`](http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rChartsExtra/d3pie/) could do this?